# How to offset when reading a changing file

Tags: java, ftp, inputstream, bufferedreader

Through JAVA, I'm reading the changing text file periodically through `InputStream` and `BufferedReader`.

For example,

```
[a minute ago]
test.txt = abcde

[now]
test.txt = cdefg
(a,b be deleted / f,g add)
```

I read all the files from the past and finished saving them to 'e'
and when I periodically re-start the program,
I want to read and save the current file from after 'e' to avoid duplication.
(I would like to read and store only f.g.)

First of all, the only way I've tried
= Searching the last 'e' from the past file from the current file
and skipped to 'e'
and then read and save it.
Of course, it works without any problems.

But, uh, the example is `abcdefg`. In alphabetical order without duplication. Assuming that it is often duplicated
For example,

```
test.txt = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

If you search for 'a', you will find out what 'a' I last read in the past file is like. There are too many redundancy values.
So, the method you've tried is not available.

Comment: You question is unclear without code.  What does *to avoid duplication* even mean?  Why not replace the value?

Comment: I already finished reading 'e' a minute ago. now file, it means reading after 'e' without reading 'e'. Because a,b,c,d,e is overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem is fundamentally impossible to solve.

Imagine the file was first

```
abcdd
```

and now it is

```
ddefg
```

There is no way to tell if the first `d` is the same in both instances. There may have been a point in time when the file looked like this:

```
cdddef
```

So the only way to do what you want to do reliably is to introduce unique markers for each entry that you can search for.

But your problem may be worse: there is no guarantee that the file stays the same while you are reading it (on most operating systems). You may have to lock it against concurrent modifications.